# Alert to the user when User moves out the dialog or closes the dialog with out saving in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Need to open an alert to the user when User moves out the dialog(inline popup ) or closes the dialog with out saving in Oracle Apex

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this do what you need?

- open page properties
- scroll down to "Navigation"
- turn **Warn on Unsaved Changes** `ON`

This is what it does:

> **Warn on Unsaved Changes**
>
> Specify if the user is warned when trying to navigate away from the page, where the page contains unsaved changes. Page Items and Buttons also offer more granular control over when this check is performed, and what is included in it. For Buttons, you can specify if clicking the button will perform the check. For Page Items, you can specify if changes to the item are included, or ignored by the check (see the Warn on Unsaved Changes attribute for both).

Comment: Do i need to create a button or item and specify the condition on that button or item for this alert